# Jenkins CI: should I have a server for Jenkins and a dedicated slave for building?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I am using Jenkins for CI,
I've heard that I should have a dedicated server and slave for running Jenkins and building tasks, respectively -
is this true?

I can understand this as the server may not be powerful enough to handle the server itself and running build tasks,
but is there any defined technical reason for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Best practice is to have a **separate** machine for Jenkins-Server,
and *not to use it for builds* at all.

This has nothing to do with CPU-power or memory-resources -

- A build-machine should have a **predefined configuration**,
  and Jenkins should not be part of it.
  (Jenkins requirements may even conflict with those of the build-machine)
- You should be able to boot / clone / upgrade / restore / trash the build-machine
  without any impact on Jenkins.

Of course you can settle for a single machine, if your resources are limited,
but if you are serious about build-automation - Jenkins should have its own server.

Answer (score 3):

You probably don't need dedicated hardware/VM to run a Jenkins server because the actual Jenkins process (no builds running) uses very little resources. But it all depends on what you want to accomplish with your Jenkins setup.

Do you want to run continuous builds across multiple platforms for multiple projects? Then using a master with slaves is the only way to go. If, on the other hand, you're running fairly simple builds for just a few projects, then you only need one machine to run the builds and the Jenkins process.

You can configure Jenkins to have multiple builds running concurrently so if you have a quad-core machine, you can safely run 2 builds and possibly a third once you analyze resource usage.

At my last gig, I used a quad-core machine with 8GB RAM to run:

- Jenkins running Selenium builds
- VirtualBox VM with Windows XP
- Two instances of Tomcat each with two applications deployed.

And the machine still had more to spare.